# Bluemix - IBM Containers problems for US South?

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

Anybody having problems with IBM Containers on US South in Bluemix?

Containers report `Data currently available` on the dashboard and if I try to list or start a container I get this error:

```
Catalog Error
×
BXNUI0513E: The attempt to retrieve containers failed because a problem occurred 
contacting IBM Containers. Try again later. If the problem continues, go to 
Support. For other help options, see the Bluemix Docs.
```

If I switch to the UK site, I can create and use containers.

I've just recently tried out a Docker container with a sshd and it was running fine for 5-6 hours. However, then it seemed like part of the Container service in Bluemix broke and I've not been able to access it for the past 24 hours.

Regards.
   Mikael

Comment: Are you using a trial account? Could you please confirm that the ssh container was created in US and not UK Region?

Comment: Hi, I'm using 'pay as you go'.


I reported it to blue mix support and they forwarded to the developers.
It started working again last night so I assume it was a local problem on my account that they resolved or was resolved by some of the maintenance work scheduled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For trial accounts you can create containers only in one space and this error sometimes occurs when the user tries to create a container in another region. Unfortunately since you're using 'pay as you go' in this in case you have to open a support request using one of the following methods in order to engage IBM Containers team to investigate your issue:

- Use the Support Widget. It is available from the user avatar in the 
     upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI.  After opening the support 
     widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch , select the type of 
     assistance you need, and then fill out the support form.
- Use the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget.  Go to http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.

EDIT: I saw that you opened a Support ticket and the issue was fixed. It was an issue related to your specific organization.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small note. Hopefully Containers in Dallas are now working well again. In addition, I wanted to note that we strongly discourage the use of sshd in containers for security reasons. The good news is shell access is at your fingertips via the `cf ic exec <contianer id> /bin/bash` command. (your container may need just `bash` or `/bin/sh` YMMV)